# Add class to selected li through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a Jquery for Dropdown menu.
It's working fine, but when I click on "li" it's opening fine but css is not being added on select li class..

**Jquery:**

```
$(".leftnav ul li").click(function () {
         $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp(400);
            $(this).find('ul').slideDown(400);      
            $(this).find('ul').addClass('activeclass'); 
            $(this).find('.leftnav ul li').addClass('activeclass1'); 
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="leftnav left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Catagories</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right left color iconpad"></i> <a href="#">Add Category</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right left color iconpad"></i><a href="#">Manage Catagories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="javascript:;">Portfolio</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right left color iconpad"></i><a href="#">Add Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right left color iconpad"></i><a href="#">Manage Portfolio</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone let me know how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry my mistake... i have edited the question now.. please help me..

Comment: Surely the last line should just be `$(this).addClass('activeclass1');` instead of `$(this).find('.leftnav ul li').addClass('activeclass1');`

Comment: use just  $(this).addClass?

Comment: I think your code is working fine :)
http://jsfiddle.net/r1uudy46/

Comment: @Moobs yes thats work, but when i click on send li the class still remains, it didn't remove from others li.. please tell me

Comment: Add `$(".leftnav ul li").removeClass('activelass1');` inside your click handler. (before you add the class)

Comment: @JoakimM do you see `activeclass1` class anywhere after click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the last line wrong as you were looking for a .leftNav class decendent from `$(this)`.  If so, this should work better for you

```
$(".leftnav ul li").click(function () {
     $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp(400);
     $(this).find('ul').slideDown(400);      
     $(this).find('ul').addClass('activeclass');

     $(this).addClass('activeclass1'); 
});
```

Comment: `.leftNav` isn't a descendant of `$(this)`. `$(this)` is a descendant of `.leftNav`

Comment: indeed, but `$(this).find('.leftnav ul li')` would be a `.leftNav` descendent from this, right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like from your example that you are doing an extra find.

```
$(".leftnav ul li").click(function () {
         $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp(400);
            $(this).find('ul').slideDown(400);      
            $(this).find('ul').addClass('activeclass'); 
            $(this).addClass('activeclass1'); // Removed "find('.leftnav ul li')"
    });
```