# How to add selected class to other li item

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add selected class to other `li` using `jQuery` or `JavaScript`:

```
<ul class="b-list" style="display: block;">
  <li data-value="bitcoin" data-name="bit" class="bitem selected"></li>
  <li data-value="tether" data-name="tet" class="bitem"></li>
  <li data-value="bitcoin-cash" data-name="bitchash" class="bitem"></li>
</ul>
```

For example add selected class for tether `li`.

Comment: `document.querySelector("li[data-value=tether]").classList.add('selected')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class to selected li through Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994898/add-class-to-selected-li-through-jquery)

Comment: @randomSoul Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: @emir_developer- It mean your `document.querySelector("li[data-value=tether]")` is returning null. I have added the answer and it is working.

Comment: It probably means you are looking for that element before it exists

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove('selected');
document.querySelector("li[data-value=tether]").classList.add('selected');
```

```css
.selected{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b-list" style="display: block;">
  <li data-value="bitcoin" data-name="bit" class="bitem selected">Item 1</li>
  <li data-value="tether" data-name="tet" class="bitem">Item 2</li>
  <li data-value="bitcoin-cash" data-name="bitchash" class="bitem">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want remove perevent selected and add new selected class

Comment: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

Comment: i want remove perevent selected and add new selected class? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes Delete the previous class and add the selected class

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:-**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.b-list li').click(function(){
      $('.b-list li').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
   });
});
```

```css
.selected{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="b-list" style="display: block;">
  <li data-value="bitcoin" data-name="bit" class="bitem selected">one</li>
  <li data-value="tether" data-name="tet" class="bitem">two</li>
  <li data-value="bitcoin-cash" data-name="bitchash" class="bitem">three</li>
</ul>
```